# Quantum Computing site?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

Should we have a quantum computing site? This site would be an intersection of physics, cryptography and software development or more.

Comment: There is a proposal in place for Quantum Computing in Area51 - should have searched that site before asking this question. Maybe I should delete this question. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing